# How to put a scrollbar in a datalist element

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, html-datalist

I'm retrieving data via XMLHttpRequest, and often the data is anywhere from 40-100 options.

Everything seems to be working great, except I can't get a scrollbar.

I am using Chrome 60.0.3112.90

I have simulated the context as much as possible using the snippet.

(Type Label into the textbox to see the results)

```js
var destination = document.getElementById('dataSource');

function inputDelayDataRetrieval(data){
  var post_data = data;
  for (i=0; i < 60; i++){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = i;
    option.label = 'Label'+ i;
    destination.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

```css
 #dataSource {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 500px;
    height: 360px;
    border: 1px silver solid;
 }
```

```html
<form>
   <input id="choiceList" type="text" maxlength="15" list="dataSource" onkeyup="inputDelayDataRetrieval(this.value)">
   <datalist id="dataSource" size="20"></datalist>
</form>
```

Any tips, or thoughts?
Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE: I don't want to use jQuery. I want to understand this issue using pure JavaScript/DOM wrangling.**

Comment: This is a known issue and has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764392/datalist-vertical-scroll-not-working-in-chrome. The best way is actually to use a custom implementation instead—also, `<datalist>` is still not supported in iOS / OS X Safari.

Comment: datalist won't support styling

Comment: stylesheet works in firefox

Comment: Ok. I've been googling all day. I don't understand why I never saw this question.

Comment: I'll try the custom implementation and see if that satisfies my requirements. Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question that still has no responsive solutions.